# Single message stuck in transmission queue

Tags: service-broker

Ok I am using service broker all other sent through service broker work fine. Except one single message is stuck in the transmission queue and will not send. Only error message I see is:

Connection attempt failed with error: '10060(A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)'.

But it's not clear that is related. Again on other messages of same message type sent are working normally.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue was Service Broker not working when XML contains special
>   characters

The issue was that in generating xml to be sent over service broker we had an á (a-acute) in our document. We overcame this issue by switching the message type from VALIDATION =
WELL_FORMED_XML to
VALIDATION = None.

We then modified
activated stored procedure on the receiving queue. Changing the line

```
@message_body = CAST(message_body as XML),

-- to

@message_body = CAST(CAST(message_body AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML),
```

This solved the issue.

I believe alternatively we could have sanitized our xml to replace the á (a-acute) with and html char code, but are use case requires us to allow the use of a lot of special characters which would be hard to id up front.

---

Connection attempt failed with error: '10060(A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)'.

This message was due a connection issue with another service broker instance running on the same server.